# completely autoremove nginx leftovers after purge of nginx?

Tags: uninstall, nginx

When I use this

```
apt-get --purge remove nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  nginx-common nginx-full
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
After this operation, 101 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 213649 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nginx (1.6.2-5) ...
root@pengsir:/home/debian8# dpkg -l nginx
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  nginx          <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

I still find some leftovers:

```
# find / -name 'nginx'
/usr/sbin/nginx
/usr/share/nginx
/etc/nginx
/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/default/nginx
/var/lib/nginx
/var/log/nginx
```

then

```
apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nginx-common nginx-full
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,339 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 213645 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nginx-full (1.6.2-5) ...
Removing nginx-common (1.6.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
```

still:

```
# find / -name 'nginx'
/etc/nginx
/etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
/etc/logrotate.d/nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx
/etc/default/nginx
/var/log/nginx
```

The files such as /usr/sbin/nginx .... are all related to nginx. I think that nginx wasn't be removed completely at all.

When we say `completely uninstall package_name`, does it mean to delete all the configuration files related the package_name?
How to remove all the files with some command efficiently?

Please do not tell to do with `find / -name 'nginx'  | rm -rf.....`.

Comment: Did you run the suggested `sudo apt-get autoremove` command to also remove the orphaned dependent packages `nginx-common` and `nginx-full`?

Comment: I have tested that it is no use to execute `apt-get autoremove` after `apt-get --purge remove nginx`,you can try too.

Comment: nginx is a dependency package so removing it removes almost nothing. The above suggestion will take care of, ie. remove  both packages (autoremove does work here, if not for you do manually..

Comment: While I never noticed before as don't use autoremove much (i use synaptic), the autoremove command does not by default purge  auto-removable packages. For that use `apt-get autoremove --purge`

Comment: do not use `find / -name 'nginx'  | rm -rf`. use `find / -name ngix -exec rm -rf {} \;` :-P

Answer (score 0):

the `autoremove` command does not by default purge auto-removable packages. For that use

```
apt-get autoremove --purge
```